# Finding an element using find_element_by_xpath

Tags: python, xpath, webdriver

I'm trying to find an element by xpath, but it does not return anything.
It seems all find_elements methods work except xpath.
I'm trying to find the text Ponderosa Campground which is clickable.

```
def searchCondition():
elem = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND']")
elem.click()
```

here is the URL where I'm trying to find the element.
https://www.recreation.gov/search?q=Ponderosa%20Campground

```
<div data-component="FocusManager" tabindex="-1" style="outline: none;">
<div class="flex-grid search-outer-wrap" data-component="FlexRow">
<div class="flex-col-12" data-component="FlexCol">
<div class="rec-flex-card-wrap " id="rec-card-233118_campground">
<a data-card="true" class="rec-flex-card-image-wrap" href="/camping/campgrounds/233118" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" alt="PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND">
<div data-component="FauxImage" class="sarsa-faux-image rec-flex-card-image-wrap-faux-image" role="img" aria-label="PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND" style="min-height: 155px; background-image: url(&quot;https://cdn.recreation.gov/public/images/76799.jpg&quot;);"></div></a>
<div class="rec-flex-card-content-wrap"><a href="/camping/campgrounds/233118" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" aria-label="PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND - 2.6 stars /  $25  / night">
```

Here is the full script.

```
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pause
import pyperclip

# Definitions
ID = ""
PW = ""
SRCH = "Ponderosa Campground"
URL = "https://www.recreation.gov/search?q=Ponderosa%20Campground"
   
now = datetime.now()
options = Options()
options.headless = False

# executable_path for webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    executable_path='C:/chromedriver.exe',
    options=options)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
driver.get(URL)

def searchClick():

CampBtn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@alt='PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND']"))).click()
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@alt='PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND']")

    if elem.isDisplayed():
        print(elem)
        elem.click()
    else:
        print("no availability")
        searchCondition()

    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: you are clicking on `div` you need to click on anchor tag `//a[@alt='PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND']` use this xpath

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't return anything? You said this is text. You aren't using `.text`. You can't click on text and text isn't going to return you anything when clicking on it. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "doesn't return anything"

Comment: Your XPath is correct.  Something else is wrong. Maybe there are more than one and the result is a array ?

Comment: `find_elements_by_xpath` returns a `list`, even if it finds only one element. `elem[0].click()` works.

Comment: @BuddyBobIII, I meant the process just ends without giving me anything. The web browser (Chrome) just closed itself. I'm trying to click the "<div class="rec-flex-card-wrap " id="rec-card-233118_campground">
<a data-card="true" class="rec-flex-card-image-wrap" href="/camping/campgrounds/233118" target="_blank" rel="noopener noreferrer" alt="PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND">
<div data-component="FauxImage" class="sarsa-faux-image rec-flex-card-image-wrap-faux-image" role="img" aria-label="PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND" ......"

Comment: @SiebeJongebloed, The browser closed itself without giving me anything. If it is correct, the link(image) must be clicked and the page should change. But, I did not see that.

Comment: @CamiloMartínez, I tried that, but the web browser closed itself without clicking the link.

Comment: @ravishankarchavare, I tried it, but it still did not work. Is there another thing I need to import? I use Chrome browser (chromedriver.exe)

Comment: Here the resources I import
import time
from time import sleep
from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import pause
import pyperclip

Comment: can you add your complete code @DJTL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to point your xpath to the interactive element for example `a`, `input`, `button`
And have to induce some explicit wait with expected condition to check that the element is all set to perform click operation. For example -

```
WebDriverWait(web, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//a[@alt='PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND']")))

elem = web.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@alt='PONDEROSA CAMPGROUND']")

elem.click()
```

After clicking on the image it opens up new tab as below. To see this operation add some wait for sometime after click operation -

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help though. I did not work.
I added the full script to my question.

Comment: @DJTL   What exception you are getting in your code?

Comment: @DJTL May be you are using default size of the browser window, do add `driver.maximize_window()` after `driver.get()`.

Comment: Also I dont see the purpose of this `if elem.isDisplayed():
        print(elem)
        elem.click()
    else:
        print("no availability")
        searchCondition()` you can do simply `elem.click()`

Comment: I changed it to this. this is working, but I don't want to use @id since it will change every time when I try a different campground.
    elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='rec-card-233118_campground']")
    if elem.is_displayed():
       elem.click()
       focuschange()
    else:
       ActionChains(driver).send_keys(Keys.F5).perform()
       searchCondition()